# XML SQL processing records to a file (memory)

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, memory

I have a working program but I'm finding processing 100,000 database records to XML file is taking too much time, this maybe due to me processing all the records into a CLOB and then writing the CLOB to the file.

I'm thinking of maybe processing the records into the clob 1000 records at a time and writing the 1000 records to the file, appending each 1000 to the same file.

The header (below) I'm thinking of hard coding and writing this to the file first.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <AV-XML xmlns="http://www.iceservices.com/0.7/AV-XML" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.iceservices.com/0.7/AV-XML AV-XML.xsd">
<Delivery>
  <supplierType>ADMIN-AGENCY</supplierType>
  <supplierId>PRS</supplierId> 
  <format>AV-XML</format>
  <creationDateTime>2016-04-05T14:31:38+0100</creationDateTime>
  <otherInformation>MIGRATION FIRST DELIVERY</otherInformation>
</Delivery>
```

After the header above the 100,000 detail records (below) are written with the message tag representing each production record (rownum). Is there a way of writing 1000 records to a clob then appending those 1000 records to the file (UTIL_FILE), is there any advice you could give me that might improve the problem I'm facing. I'm using XMLELEMENT and XMLFOREST and I'm on a Oracle 11g database.

I will then hard code the end tag  at the end.

```
<Message>
  <messageSequenceId>1</messageSequenceId>
  <messageType>NEW</messageType>
  <otherInformation>MIGRATION FIRST DELIVERY</otherInformation>
  <Production>
    <prodCategoryType>COMMERCIAL</prodCategoryType>
    <prodStatusType>SKELETON</prodStatusType>
    <prodActive>true</prodActive>
    <prodCueStatusType>WAIT</prodCueStatusType>
    <prodTvInhouse>Y</prodTvInhouse>
    <prodTitle>
      <title>BOB MOBILE</title>
      <titleType>ORIGINAL</titleType>
    </prodTitle>
    <prodId>
      <idType>SOCIETY-ID</idType>
      <id>74644854</id>
    </prodId>
  </Production>
</Message>
```

I'm trying to reduce the memory that it's consuming when trying to process all the 100,000 records.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much time is too much, and are you worried about time, memory or both (as you've mentioned both in the question)? Have you timed the XML generation and the writing out to the file separately? Are you making copies of the XML and/or CLOB when you don't need to?

Comment: Well I'm worried about both, it does just 1000 records in 12 minutes, to do 100,000 records that would be 20 hours. So I'm looking at ways to bring this down. The SQL seems to be quick but it's the actual writing to the file that seems to take the time.

Comment: It shouldn't take that long to query *or* write. 'Seems to' is slightly worrying, have you actually timed both parts? If it is the write then splitting it up probably won't help much. I seem to recall that the 100k are from a much larger table, so I'd guess it doesn't much matter at the moment if you're getting 1k, 10k or 100k, and it's more likely that query needs tuning.

Comment: I'll take more of a look at the query and try to tune it down a little more.. thanks for the advice once again Alex Poole, your always a big help.

Comment: @ShaunKinnair you should profile the actual query you're running as running it in your editor may be giving a false impression. My IDE (Toad) automatically optimizes for the fastest query to retrieve the first few rows, rather than the entire data set. I've run into issues where I thought my SQL was fast but it was actually extremely slow when fetching the entire data set.

Comment: I would suggest you check the EXPLAIN PLAN for your query as well - you may be doing unnecessary FULL TABLE SCANS or not using your existing indexes. Also, if you're running this in a package or procedure, check out the DMBS_PROFILER (http://www.oraclerecipes.com/tuning/using-dbms-profiler-to-find-bottleneck-in-a-procedure) to help identify exactly where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Thanks Joel, I'll run it through the DBMS_PROFILER if I have access to this tool and it's tables. Thanks for your advice.